# Selecting all list items with a certain class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I pick all the `<li>` items on my DOM having the class `.tab`, using jQuery? `$('.tab')`returns all the DOM elements having `.tab`, but I want only the `<li>` elements to be selected.

Comment: I don't believe for a minute that even minimal research would have not shown you how to do this.

Comment: @cookiemonster:  Please point out to me another question on Stackoverflow asking for something similar. If you cannot do that, I request you to kindly reconsider your decision to down-vote me. Thanks.

Comment: This is the most basic of basic functions when using jQuery or CSS style selectors in general. It's expected that an asker have at least a rudimentary knowledge of the technology being used. I stand behind my vote. StackOverflow is not a substitute for basic research (beginner tutorials and documentation).

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$('li.tab');
```

That is the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) plus [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Notice that you can't have spaces. As `li .tab` would mean "all elements with the class `tab` that are children of a `<li>`".

Answer (score 0):

Combine element selector with class selector

```
$("li.tab")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax  -

```
$("li.tab")
```

Answer (score 0):

just add li. This is correct syntex

```
$("li.tab")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GAg2u/) output will be at `console`